# Generate tex file containing all filenames in a directory

Tags: directory, echo, printf, latex

I have a folder containing 95 tex files. I need to create a tex file all.tex that contains the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\input{file1.tex}
\input{file2.tex}
...
\input{file95.tex}
\end{document}
```

The file names do *not* have any pattern and hence I cannot use a loop. The above is just a working example.

I tried the following on bash:

```
printf '%s\n' *.tex | paste -sd "\n" - > all.tex
```

That creates an all.tex file that looks like this:

```
file1.tex
file2.tex
...
file95.tex
```

**How do I add \input{} around the filenames? And how do I add the preamble etc.?**

I am using [bash (on Ubuntu)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) on Windows 10.

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7657 could help

Answer (score 4):

In a simple shell script, using `printf` and simple wildcard expansion:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' '\documentclass[10pt]{article}' \
              '\begin{document}'

printf '\input{%s}\n' *.tex

printf '%s\n' '\end{document}'
```

You would call that script and redirect the output, such as:

```
/path/to/script > /path/of/output.tex
```

On a single command-line, you might group the prints together for a single redirect:

```
{ printf '%s\n' '\documentclass[10pt]{article}' \
              '\begin{document}'
printf '\input{%s}\n' *.tex
printf '%s\n' '\end{document}'
} > /path/of/output.tex
```

Comment: I'm curious, why didn't you apply the output redirection directly in the script ?

Comment: You certainly could, if you always had the same filename; I left it open to be more in line with a typical UNIX filter.

Comment: Valid point, although you could still call the script with a parameter for the filename ;)

Comment: [TMTOWTDI!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Here's a dumb question. I am failing to execute the shell script (I only ever run straight from the command line but this time I need to run it from a script). I copy-pasted your code into a combine.sh (both with and without #!/bin/sh) and then ran sh combine.sh > all.tex. I get : not found 1: combine.sh \begin{document}.

Comment: I don't have a WSL environment to confirm, but in general you would need to make that script executable with `chmod u+x combine.sh`...

Answer (score 0):

A regular Ubuntu by default has perl installed so you can do it like this:

`ls *tex | perl -pne 's/(.*)/\\input{$1}/' > allfiles.tex`

It could be that it's not installed yet on Ubuntu on Windows, if this is the case `apt-get install perl-base` will do the trick.

**EDIT:** If perl is not available and you don't want to install it, you could also use sed:

`ls *tex | sed 's/\(.*tex\)/\\input{\1}/' > allfiles.tex`

(But I always recommend the more powerful perl)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best, but here's a solution using `sed` to edit your `all.tex` file:

```
sed -e 's/^/\\input\{/g' -e 's/$/\}/g' all.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN     { print "\\documentclass[10pt]{article}"
                print "\\begin{document}" }
    BEGINFILE { printf("\\include{%s}\n", FILENAME); nextfile }
    END       { print "\\end{document}" }' *.tex
```

This would produce a list such as the one you show, with the files listed in the order that the shell expands the filename globbing pattern `*.tex`.

For files named `file1.tex` through to `file95.tex`, this will *not* be in numerical order.  For that, you may want to switch over to the `zsh` shell and use the `file<1-95>.tex` globbing pattern instead, or the more relaxed pattern `*.tex(n)`.